# android onclicklistener not working (inspite of registering)

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have an activity that runs as a theme dialog. This is the code for the button clicklistener. However the control never enters the onClick(). Theres no error in the console. In the logcat I get this (in green) - The application may be doing too much work in tis main thread.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ....
 var_btnDisconnectDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisconnectDone);
 var_btnDisconnectDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            intFromTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromH.getText().toString());
            intFromTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromM.getText().toString());
            intToTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToH.getText().toString());
            intToTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToM.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisconnectDone"
    ...
    android:onClick="what do I add here??"
    android:text="@string/btnSave_hint" />
```

[image: 1]

Comment: your naming convention is not following java standards. var_blah isconfusing. You should rename member variables to be mMyVariableNameHere. Also what do you mean bye "runs as a theme dialog"? This makes no sense. Please update and be more clear.

Comment: @Adi can you post some more code ?

Comment: so does it HAVE TO BE mblah ?? by theme dialog I mean this -  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" (in the manifest)

Comment: @GrlsHu: Like what else should I add?

Comment: @Adi Have you defined `onClick` property in your xml file also ? If you have defined then you just need to write method name which you want to execute while the click event is performed in your xml file. And create method in your class file and write the logic inside it and it will automatically executed whenever the button is clicked.

Comment: what is the difference between defining the onclick directly in the XML and defining it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined then you just need to write method name which you want to execute while the click event is performed in your xml file. And create method in your class file and write the logic inside it and it will automatically executed whenever the button is clicked.

`android:onClick` was added in API level 4 to make it easier, more Javascript-web-like, and drive everything from the XML. What it does internally is add an `OnClickListener` on the `Button`.

Here is what using a `android:onClick="DoIt"` does internally:

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //Your logic here.
    }
});
```

The only thing you trade off by using `android:onClick`, as usual with XML configuration, is that it becomes a bit more difficult to add dynamic content (programatically, you could decide to add one listener or another depending on your variables). But this is easily defeated by adding your test within the `DoIt` method.

And if you want to define it from xml then Do as below:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisconnectDone"
    ...
    android:onClick="ClickEvent"
    android:text="@string/btnSave_hint" />
```

And in your class file write a method.

```
  public void ClickEvent(View v){
   //Your logic here.
    }
```

Comment: why cant it find the method now (I am donig it with XML onClick)?

Comment: ok its entering the method now... just one thing, How do I dismiss the dialog?

Comment: Which dialog you are talking about ?

Comment: the one in the image (see my original post). The activity is displayed as a dialog which should disappear when I click DONE.

Comment: As you have declared your activity as dialog then to finish it you just need to call `finish();` and it will finish the activity onclick of done button .

Answer (score 1):

Use  `@Override`

```
    var_btnDisconnectDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  intFromTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromH.getText().toString());
    intFromTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromM.getText().toString());
    intToTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToH.getText().toString());
    intToTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToM.getText().toString()); 
                }
            });
```

Remove  `android:onClick="what do I add here??"` this line from XML

Comment: did, its still not working! Also, the dialog doesnt get dismissed when I click DONE!

Answer (score 0):

you did not overrride the click function

see this and check if it works

```
     var_btnDisconnectDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      intFromTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromH.getText().toString());
        intFromTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtFromM.getText().toString());
        intToTimeH = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToH.getText().toString());
        intToTimeM = Integer.parseInt(var_txtToM.getText().toString()); 
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The line that you erased (var_btnDisconnectDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {) is required for registering the onclicklistener. Is it not required?

Comment: it is required.. just add the override notation and try.. else implement the onClickLiatner